# Как в js проверить есть ли строка массива в другом массиве и если нет, то записать туда

Tags: javascript

Есть многомерный массив

```
var data_array = [
["первая строка"],
["вторая строка"],
["третья строка"],
["четвертая строка"],
["пятая строка"],
];
```

При помощи функции

```
var rand = data_array[Math.floor(Math.random()*data_array.length)];
```

Из него выбрана рандомная строка

И второй массив

```
var prov = [];
```

Как теперь проверить, есть ли эта рандомная строка во втором массиве? И если нет, то как записать её на i-ую позицию.

Comment: Что значит записать на `i`-ую позицию? + Ваш массив не валидный. каждый элемент должен быть разделен `,`, а не как у вас `;`

Comment: Ой, с точкой запятой это я накосячила, да Проверка и запись массива происходит в цикле while

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы пишите,что выбираете рандомную строку,то для чего все усложнять и указывать многомерный массив.
В вашем случае, вы получаете не строку,а объект `typeof rand`
Для проверки есть метод indexOf().
Для записи на i-ую позицию есть метод splice.

Пример:

```js
const data_array = [
"первая строка",
"вторая строка",
"третья строка",
"четвертая строка",
"пятая строка",
];

const prov = [
"первая строка",
"вторая строка",
];

let rand = data_array[Math.random() * data_array.length ^ 0];

console.log(rand);

if(!~prov.indexOf(rand)) {
 prov.splice(0,0,rand);
}

console.log(prov);
```

Comment: `indexOf` c `~`, а я все думал, где это может пригодится)